# Instagram API: Any way to increase result returned from hash tag based query?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I recenty saw change imposed by instagram on sandbox account that limits returned result to last 20 recent images https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/#api-behavior.

I need to fetch last six tag based images but in last 20 image there are 3 images with that hash tag.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not just last 20 posts in Sandboc Mode, its also last 20 posts from your app's sandbox users. This is a limitation of Sandbox mode.

> The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as
>   when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:
>
> - Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user
> - Reduced API rate limits

Only way to get all is to go live.

Comment: How can I make my app live? When I select option **I want to display my Instagram posts on my website.** I do not see any way to make it live.

Comment: you have to get your app reviewed and after the app is approved, you will have an option to go live

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zk54zv0wb0rlfo/Instagram%20Developer%20Documentation.jpg?dl=0 is what I see. There is no way to submit with option I need. I may be wrong but I am unable to find a way to make my app live.

Comment: Only selecting the last 3 above "other" will allow you to proceed to next step, if your app does not meet those 3, you will not get approved